# Communication between components Angular9.1.10

Tags: angular

i have problem with the communication between components.

Component A : this component have a form this information is sent to a API and wait for response when i have the response then change to the Component B and draw the response

Component B : this component draw the response from server

I tried using eventemmiter and also using a var from a service of this way

service

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectService{
    public url:string;
    public report: string;
    @Output() change: EventEmitter<string>;
    

    constructor(
        private http:HttpClient
    ) {
        this.change =   new EventEmitter();
        this.url = Global.url
    }
    change_data(data){        
      this.report= data;
      this.change.emit(data) 
    }
```

component A

```
onSubmit(form){ 

console.log("send")
this.projectService.getReport(this.project).subscribe(data=>{
  
 this.projectService.change_data("change");
  
  console.log("proyecto",this.projectService.report)
  
  this._router.navigate(['/reporte'])      
}, err=>{
  console.error("error",err)
});
```

}

Component B

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService.change.subscribe(data=>{
      this.test = data;
    })
    console.log("report"+ this.test);
    this.test = this.projectService.report;



  }
```

In this moment no use the response from server because i am testing this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a little adjustment in your service:

```
change = BehaviorSubject(null);
...
this.change.next(data);
```

1: @Output() in service is useless. it just does nothing so i removed it

2: `change` is changed to BehaviorSubject - tricky subject where you get the last value at the moment you subscribe. with just EventEmitter you've subscribed after the data is `emit`ted and lost that value.

3: next instead of emit just because simple subject doesn't have `emit` method. `next` does exactly the same (btw there is next method on EventEmitter)

Comment: thanks for the advice implement this but no work for me :(...arrive the value null